# Unable to use 'console.log' after redirecting it to 'alert'

Tags: javascript, node.js, alert, console.log

I have implemented a JS module which I use from several Node.js scripts.

I would like to be able to use this module also from a browser, and I would like all messages to be displayed in an HTML alert box instead of in the terminal.

Ideally, I would like to achieve this without changing my JS module (for example, by replacing all occurrences of `console.log` with `alert`, or by passing the logging function when I initialize the module).

So I've figured I could simply set `console.log = alert` right before I use this module from the client-side code that I have.

For all it matters, I am actually doing it with [Electron](https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron) (cross-platform desktop applications using JavaScript), but I have also tested it on a browser, and the result is the same.

With `console.log = alert`, I successfully change `console.log` from `function log() {[native code]}` into into `function alert() {[native code]}`.

However, when I then attempt to call `console.log("test")`, I get an exception `TypeError: Illegal invocation`.

Here is a simple client-side code which reproduces this problem:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            try{
                alert(`before:\n- alert = ${alert}\n- console.log = ${console.log}`);
                console.log = alert;
                alert(`after:\n- alert = ${alert}\n- console.log = ${console.log}`);
                console.log("test");
            }
            catch (error) {
                alert(error);
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Why am I getting this problem, and how I may resolve it (ideally without changing my JS module)?

Is it possible that `alert` eventually calls `console.log`, which yields some sort of infinite recursion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value of `this` matters.

`alert` expects `this` to be `window` not `console`.

Thus:

```
console.log = window.alert.bind(window);
```

Comment: Awesome, someone here has just suggested for me that this is the reason. Does the bottom line resolve my problem?

Comment: Yes if you do that instead of `console.log = alert;`. This works cause you change property `log` of the object `console` which makes the console object `this` by binding `window` (so window is `this`) to the function it functions normal again   P.s. `console.log = alert.bind(window)` works too cause all global variables are actually in the window object.